# Migrar vista .Net Framework 4.5 a .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Tengo un proyecto en el Framework 4.5 el cual estoy migrando a Core 2.2, me encontré con la siguiente vista:

```
@model TransporteViewModel
<form id="frmPrincipal">
  <section id="DatosPrincipales">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h4 class="sub-title">Datos</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="vendedor">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.FormGroup(m => m.Dni, Column.col_sm_4).TextBox(new { disabled = true })
            @Html.FormGroup(m => m.FechaEmi, Column.col_sm_4).TextBox(new { disabled = true, Value = Model != null ? Model.FechaEmi.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty })
        </div>   
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

Necesito pasar este código a .Net Core 2.2 pero cuando intento agregar `@Html.FormGroup()` me marca un error que dice:

> "IHtmlHelper" no contiene una definición para "FormGroup" ni un método de extensión accesible "FormGroup" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "IHtmlHelper" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

De qué manera puedo remplazar este FormGroup?

No tengo mucha experiencia en Net Core y es mi primera migración por lo que estoy un poco confundido al menos por ahora con la vista.

TransporteViewModel.cs

```
public class TransporteViewModel : GridData
{
    [Display(Name = "Productor")]
    public int? IdProductor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "FechaEmi:")]
    public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

de acuerdo a la documentación de ASP.NET Core, ya no existen los Html Helpers como lo conocíamos. Para migrar el código en cuestión, debes ver los [Tag Helpers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form)

Entonces, las líneas que tenías como:

```
@Html.FormGroup(m => m.Dni, Column.col_sm_4).TextBox(new { disabled = true })
```

Quedarían algo así:

```
<input asp-for="Dni" class="col-sm-4" disabled />
```

Recuerda que debes agregar al principio del archivo html el uso de los Tag helpers:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```